# Align `div`or `span` element to bottom

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

How to change the code so the `tabs`are aligned to the bottom of the `div`

I have this code

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-12">
        <h1 class="page-header"><?php if(file_exists($find_logo[0])) { echo '<img style="max-width:275px; max-height:80px; height:auto; width:auto;" src="'.$find_logo[0].'" />'; }?><span class="small pull-right" data-toggle="popover"><i class="fas fa-question-circle"></i></span>
        <span class="pull-right">
        <h5>
            <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
                <li role="presentation" <?php if($page_tabs == 'details') { echo 'class="active"'; } ?>><a href="dossier_detail.php?id=<?php echo $_GET['id']; ?>"><i class="fas fa-home"></i> Algemeen</a></li>
                <li role="presentation" <?php if($page_tabs == 'documenten') { echo 'class="active"'; } ?>><a href="dossier_detail_documenten.php?id=<?php echo $_GET['id']; ?>"><i class="fas fa-file-invoice-dollar"></i> Documenten</a></li>
                <li role="presentation" <?php if($page_tabs == 'calculaties') { echo 'class="active"'; } ?>><a href="dossier_detail_calculaties.php?id=<?php echo $_GET['id']; ?>"><i class="fas fa-calculator"></i> Calculaties</a></li>
                <li role="presentation" <?php if($page_tabs == 'certificaten') { echo 'class="active"'; } if($row['soort'] == 'offerte') { echo 'class="disabled"'; } ?>><a href="dossier_detail_certificaten.php?id=<?php echo $_GET['id']; ?>"><i class="fas fa-file-contract"></i> Certificaten</a></li>
                <li role="presentation" <?php if($page_tabs == 'bestanden') { echo 'class="active"'; } ?>><a href="dossier_detail_bestanden.php?id=<?php echo $_GET['id']; ?>"><i class="fas fa-copy"></i> Bestanden</a></li>
            </ul>
        </h5>
        </span>
        </h1>
    </div>
</div>
```

That results that the `tabs` are aligned in the middle
[image]
[image]

With changing `<span class="pull-right">` to `<span class="pull-right" style="padding-top:38px;">` I was hoping to achieve (also tried this on the other elements).
[image]

But this add-on is not giving me any result? How to achieve this?

Comment: [Flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) is perfect for vertical alignment. You could also use absolute or relative positioning.

Answer (score 2):

Initially you need to restructure you html code. See below example

**Your code have, html validation issues**

- Nested heading not allowed
- h5 element not allowed as child of element span
- ul is not allowed child of h5

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-2 col-md-3">
      <h1 class="page-header">
        <img style="max-width:275px; max-height:80px; height:auto; width:auto;" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/browser-logos/62.2.7/chromium/chromium_48x48.png" alt="" />
        <span class="small pull-right" data-toggle="popover"><i class="fas fa-question-circle"></i></span>
      </h1>
    </div>
    <!-- end col -->
    <div class="col-10 col-md-9 align-self-end">
      <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
        <li role="presentation" ><a href="dossier_detail.php?id="><i class="fas fa-home"></i> Algemeen</a></li>
        <li role="presentation" ><a href="dossier_detail_documenten.php?id="><i class="fas fa-file-invoice-dollar"></i> Documenten</a></li>
        <li role="presentation" ><a href="dossier_detail_calculaties.php?id="><i class="fas fa-calculator"></i> Calculaties</a></li>
        <li role="presentation" ><a href="dossier_detail_certificaten.php?id="><i class="fas fa-file-contract"></i> Certificaten</a></li>
        <li role="presentation" ><a href="dossier_detail_bestanden.php?id="><i class="fas fa-copy"></i> Bestanden</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <!-- end col -->
  </div>
  <!-- end row -->
</div>
```